# Need to output HTML's attributes { and } and : using XSL

Tags: xslt

have some HTML with attribute value contains { , } and : needed to be generated using XSL

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/"><ul>
                <li data-jstree="{ 'icon' : 'fa fa-briefcase icon-state-success ' }"/></ul></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above give an error :The stylesheet does not contain a document element. The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML document.

Comment: If you actually have that space before `<?xml`, remove it.

Comment: The space before `<?xml` doesn't affect the output, @GSerg.

Comment: Space before `<?xml` [makes the entire XSL file invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11959378/11683), @ObinnaNwakwue.